# How can I create a Stripe checkout with custom amount to be paid?

Tags: stripe-payments

When creating a checkout session, I am providing line items with `price_data` and `quantity` and in the checkout I see the correct amount. For some payments the customer can use their in-app points which will reduce some amount from the total checkout amount. How can I apply that to the checkout?

Example:
You buy 3 T-shirts (3x20) and one cap (1x15) which means you need to pay 75.00 (of some unit)
You use the in-app option to use your points which gives you 5.00, so now your checkout session must be a custom value (70.00).

I am using this API:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create

The only solution that I came up with was to create a [coupon](https://stripe.com/docs/api/coupons) right before creating the checkout and apply it to the checkout, but I don't know if that's safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes [coupon should works with Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/discounts).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work.

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("YOUR_STRIPE_SECRET");

stripe.checkout.sessions.create(
  {
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: [
      {
        price: "YOUR_PRICE_ID",
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    success_url: "https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
cancel_url: "https://example.com/cancel",
  },
  function(err, session) {
    console.log(session.id);
  }
);
```